# Percona xtradb cluster with asynch slaves

Tags: replication, master-slave, percona

I have a Percona xtradb cluster set up with 3 nodes.  Node 1 is also set up as a master with an asynchronous slave.  When I make an update to Node 1, it is replicated to the cluster as well as the slave.  However, when I make an update to Node 2 or Node 3 the slave does not replicate Node 1.

When an update is made on node 2 or node 3, node1 doesn't update his bin-log.

How can I get the bin logs to stay up to date?

And if all three nodes were masters to asynch slaves how can I keep all 3 bin-logs the same?

Answer (score 0):

To have the transactions written on node 2 and node 3 on node 1, you should enable log_slave_updates (log_slave_updates=1 in my.cnf). However, this does not mean the binary logs will be exactly the same. They will contain the same events, but the file name and the position belonging to a certain event on a given node can be different from others.